# Como solucionar el error 500 en python fastAPI

Tags: python, api

Estoy por terminar un curso de programación, específicamente con Python y castaño

Y tengo el siguiente problema:

> raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_) >pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Person esponse value is not a valid dict (type-type_error.dict)

El código:

```py
class PersonBase(BaseModel):
    first_name: str = Field(
        ...,
        min_length=1,
        max_length=50,
        example="yeifrer"
    )
    last_name: str = Field(
        ...,
        min_length=1,
        max_length=50,
        example="surita"
    )
    age: int = Field(
        ...,
        gt=0,
        le=115,
        example=17
    )
    hair_color: Optional[Hair_color] = Field(
        default=None,
        example="black"
        )
    is_married: Optional[bool] = Field(
        default=None,
        example=False
        )
class Person(PersonBase):

    password: str = Field(
        ...,
        min_length=8,
    )

class PersonOut(PersonBase):
    pass
```

Comment: ¿Es "black" un objeto válido de la clase `Hair_color`?

Comment: No creo que el problema esté en las clases. El problema esta al retornar la respuesta de la petición. Podrías colocar el código completo y especificar cuando aparece el error?

Comment: A lo primero, si black es un objeto válido, lo realicé con Enum

Comment: me dice que como es mucho codigo no lo puedo agregar. que hago?

Comment: No edites el título indicando que el problema fue resuelto. En su lugar agrega una respuesta en la sección de respuestas